# Are Atoms and ions actually mini solar systems?

Tags: atomic-physics, solar-system

If you look at an Atom, don't you notice it works much like our solar system,
and if they are solar systems then we might be an Atom.

Comment: Not quite. See for example http://www.chemistry.mcmaster.ca/aim/aim_1.html

Comment: this is not about physics of 21st century

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are definitely some similarities between the solar system and the bohr model. But it is a gross oversimplification and even then there are many differences. There is no similarity between the solar system and newer and much more accurate quantum mechanical model of the atom.

http://www.school-for-champions.com/science/atoms_solar_systems.htm#.Wm32Ya6WbIU
https://www.quora.com/What-if-our-Solar-System-is-an-atom-and-Sun-is-the-nucleus-and-we-are-sub-atomic-particles

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

No, atoms are not mini solar systems.

The solar system is held together by gravitational forces, with planets orbiting the sun under the action of gravity.

In the atom, electrons are bound to the nucleus by the electromagnetic force (the first difference) and obey quantum mechanics rather than classical mechanics (difference two).

In some simplified models electrons are said to 'orbit' the nucleus, however, this is not the case. Electrons exist in energy levels and obey probabilistic rules.

Planets, on the other hand, obey classical mechanics (or I suppose you could say general relativity) and so have well defined deterministic trajectories.